# Incorrect facenet recognition

Tags: python, opencv, face-detection, face-recognition

I've been working on a face recognition attendance management system. I've built the pipeline from scratch but in the end,the script recognizes the wrong face among a group of 10 classes.
I've implemented the following pipeline using Tensorflow and Python.

1. Capture images, resize, align them using dlib's shape predictor and store them in named folders for later comparison while performing recognition.
2. Pickle the images into a `data.pickle` file for later deserialization.
3. Using OpenCV to implement MTCNN algorithm to detect faces in a frame captured by webcam
4. passing these frames into a facenet network to create 128-D embeddings and compared accordingly with the embeddings present in pickle database.

Given Below is the main file which runs step 3 and 4:

```
from keras import backend as K
import time
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool
K.set_image_data_format('channels_first')
import cv2
import os
import glob
import numpy as np
from numpy import genfromtxt
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import load_model
from fr_utils import *
from inception_blocks_v2 import *
from mtcnn.mtcnn import MTCNN
import dlib
from imutils import face_utils
import imutils
import pickle
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split


FRmodel = load_model('face-rec_Google.h5')
# detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
detector = MTCNN()
# FRmodel = faceRecoModel(input_shape=(3, 96, 96))
#
# # detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
# # predictor = dlib.shape_predictor("shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat")
# def triplet_loss(y_true, y_pred, alpha = 0.3):
#     """
#     Implementation of the triplet loss as defined by formula (3)
#
#     Arguments:
#     y_pred -- python list containing three objects:
#             anchor -- the encodings for the anchor images, of shape (None, 128)
#             positive -- the encodings for the positive images, of shape (None, 128)
#             negative -- the encodings for the negative images, of shape (None, 128)
#
#     Returns:
#     loss -- real number, value of the loss
#     """
#
#     anchor, positive, negative = y_pred[0], y_pred[1], y_pred[2]
#
#     pos_dist = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(tf.subtract(anchor, positive)), axis=-1)
#     neg_dist = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(tf.subtract(anchor, negative)), axis=-1)
#     basic_loss = tf.add(tf.subtract(pos_dist, neg_dist), alpha)
#     loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.maximum(basic_loss, 0.0))
#
#     return loss
#
# FRmodel.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = triplet_loss, metrics = ['accuracy'])
# load_weights_from_FaceNet(FRmodel)
def ret_model():
    return FRmodel

def prepare_database():
    pickle_in = open("data.pickle","rb")
    database =  pickle.load(pickle_in)
    return database

def unpickle_something(pickle_file):
    pickle_in = open(pickle_file,"rb")
    unpickled_file =  pickle.load(pickle_in)
    return unpickled_file


def webcam_face_recognizer(database):

    cv2.namedWindow("preview")
    vc = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    while vc.isOpened():
        ret, frame = vc.read()
        img_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        img = frame
        # We do not want to detect a new identity while the program is in the process of identifying another person
        img = process_frame(img,img)

        cv2.imshow("Preview", img)
        cv2.waitKey(1)

    vc.release()

def process_frame(img, frame):
    """
    Determine whether the current frame contains the faces of people from our database
    """
    # rects = detector(img)
    rects = detector.detect_faces(img)
    # Loop through all the faces detected and determine whether or not they are in the database
    identities = []
    for (i,rect) in enumerate(rects):
        (x,y,w,h) = rect['box'][0],rect['box'][1],rect['box'][2],rect['box'][3]
        img = cv2.rectangle(frame,(x, y),(x+w, y+h),(255,0,0),2)

        identity = find_identity(frame, x-50, y-50, x+w+50, y+h+50)
        cv2.putText(img, identity,(10,500), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX , 4,(255,255,255),2,cv2.LINE_AA)

        if identity is not None:
            identities.append(identity)

    if identities != []:
        cv2.imwrite('example.png',img)

    return img

def find_identity(frame, x,y,w,h):
    """
    Determine whether the face contained within the bounding box exists in our database

    x1,y1_____________
    |                 |
    |                 |
    |_________________x2,y2

    """
    height, width, channels = frame.shape
    # The padding is necessary since the OpenCV face detector creates the bounding box around the face and not the head
    part_image = frame[y:y+h, x:x+w]

    return who_is_it(part_image, database, FRmodel)

def who_is_it(image, database, model):

    encoding = img_to_encoding(image, model)


    min_dist = 100
    # Loop over the database dictionary's names and encodings.
    for (name, db_enc) in database.items():

        # Compute L2 distance between the target "encoding" and the current "emb" from the database.
        dist = np.linalg.norm(db_enc.flatten() - encoding.flatten())

        print('distance for %s is %s' %(name, dist))

        # If this distance is less than the min_dist, then set min_dist to dist, and identity to name
        if dist < min_dist:
            min_dist = dist
            identity = name

        if min_dist >0.1:
            print('Unknown person')
        else:
            print(identity)
    return identity


if __name__ == "__main__":
    database = prepare_database()
    webcam_face_recognizer(database)
```

What am I doing wrong here?
**Here the FRmodel is the facenet trained model**

Answer (score 0):

Few points:

- I don't see resizing, aligning and whitening of the input face image that is fed into the network.
- You cannot add a fixed margin of 50 to a variable-sized face. There has to be a scaling such that the face region fills almost the same region in every input image.
- I am not sure about the model you are using, but if you are using [FaceNet](https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.03832), your accepted matching threshold, 0.1, seems to be very low. It will not accept any matches unless it is the same exact image (with a distance of 0.0), or has a very minimal variation from the gallery image.